# Is it possible to create a hive table from a specific subset of CSV columns?

Tags: csv, hadoop, select, hive

I have approximately 400 CSV files.  I want to create a Hive table over these CSV files but only include a certain subset of the columns (see below).  I know I could create a table with all of them then use a select statement to grab only the ones I want and make a second hive table but I was wondering if there was a way I could avoid doing that.

here are my columns:

```
columns = ['time', 'Var2', 'Var3', 'Var4', 'Var5', 'Var6', 'Var7', 'I0', 'I1',
       'I2', 'V0', 'V1', 'V2', 'fpa', 'fpb', 'fpc', 'fpg', 'filename',
       'record_time_stamp', 'fault', 'unix_time', 'Var2_real', 'Var2_imag',
       'Var3_real', 'Var3_imag', 'Var4_real', 'Var4_imag', 'Var5_real',
       'Var5_imag', 'Var6_real', 'Var6_imag', 'Var7_real', 'Var7_imag',
       'I0_real', 'I0_imag', 'I1_real', 'I1_imag', 'I2_real', 'I2_imag',
       'V0_real', 'V0_imag', 'V1_real', 'V1_imag', 'V2_real', 'V2_imag']
```

I don't want these in the Hive table :

```
['Var2', 'Var3', 'Var4', 'Var5', 'Var6', 'Var7', 'I0', 'I1','I2', 'V0', 'V1', 'V2']
```

I understand I can just alter my data in the CSVs or use 2 Hive tables but I don't want to alter my data (because another team will use those columns for their work) and I don't want to make another table for the sake of keeping things neat.  Is this possible?

Comment: Create a view .........

Comment: doesn't this still have the outcome of having 2 different tables? can i create a view from just csv files in a directory?

Comment: No, the data is in the files and all the rest is in the metadata level. Create an external table over the directory and view over the external table. P.s. you could do what you want in a single step, by creating an external table with regex serde, but it doesn't worth the bother.

Comment: Thanks! This sounds like a good solution and I'll give it a shot!

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In case you can use Spark, I'd suggest you read the data from the CSV file, create a data model of the columns that you need and then enforce it on the RDD you have ingested with your application to create a dataframe.
Save the dataframe thereafter using the .saveAsTable( ) and you should see this in your Hive Database.

Manipulation of data to such an extent is a task for Spark and not Hive.